# How to construct a function in $C_{wk}([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$, but may not in $C([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, bochner-spaces

The question is in the third chapter of this book
http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/gsm-192

The notation $C_{wk}([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$ mean:
A function f(t):$[0,T]\to L^2(\Omega)$ is said to be in $C_{wk}([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$ if for any $t_0\in [0,T]$ and $w\in (L^2(\Omega))^*,$
$\int_{\Omega}f(x,t)\cdot w(x)\,dx\to\int_{\Omega}f(x,t_o)\cdot w(x)\,dx$ as $t\to t_0.$

I have thought about using a concept similar to the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma to try, but there is something wrong.

This may be an overly simple question, but I really can’t figure it out,Can someone provide any good  textbooks or reference ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take any $F\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and define $f(x,t) = F(x-1/t)$ for $t\neq 0$ and $f(x,0) = 0$. This function is not strongly continuous at $t=0$, so it is not in $C([0,1], L^2(\mathbb{R}))$, but it is weakly continuous everywhere. If $\Omega$ is bounded you may use examples like $f(x,t) = \psi e^{x/t}$ for some $\psi$.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter.